# Nginx - choose the location according to URI

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I would like to choose the locations according to URI.
The request `http://example.com/?key=Qde(*s0` would go to location A.
The request `http://example.com/?key=Qde(*s1` would go to location B.

Is it possible to do it? The main problem is with question mark in URI, which can't be used in regex in the location.

When I use something like this, it also doesn't work
`location ~* (.*)(key\=Qde\(\*s01)`

I tried the different regex in location.